# Making question marks on PDF file readable

Tags: java, html, pdf, jsoup, converters

I've parsed a webpage with a URL that's basically a page that force-downloads the PDF that is on the page. With the ignorecontenttype() method from Jsoup I managed to display a whole bunch of text but it contains question marks in black ovals like this:
Here is my code:

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document document1 = null;
Connection.Response downloadPopUp = Jsoup.connect("https://www.capitaliq.com/ciqdotnet/login.aspx?redirect=%2fCIQDotNet%2fFilings%2fDocumentRedirector.axd%3fversionId%3d" + ID + "%26type%3dpdf%26forcedownload%3dtrue/login.php").userAgent("Chrome/44.0.2403.125")
     .method(Connection.Method.GET)
     .timeout(1000000)
     .ignoreContentType(true)
     .execute();
document1 = Jsoup.connect("https://www.capitaliq.com/ciqdotnet/login.aspx?redirect=%2fCIQDotNet%2fFilings%2fDocumentRedirector.axd%3fversionId%3d" + ID + "%26type%3dpdf%26forcedownload%3dtrue").userAgent("Chrome/44.0.2403.125")
     .data("cookieexists", "false")
     .data("myLogin$myUsername", "MyEmail")
     .data("myLogin$myPassword", "MyPassword")
     .data("myLogin$myLoginButton.x", "22")
     .data("myLogin$myLoginButton.y", "8")
     .data("__VIEWSTATE", viewState)
     .data("__EVENTVALIDATION", eventValidation)
     .data("myLogin$myEnableAutoLogin", "on")
     .timeout(1000000)
     .cookies(downloadPopUp.cookies())

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
```

%PDF-1.3 %���� 1 0 obj<>endobj 2 0 obj<>endobj 3 0 obj<>stream x��ctem�6۶mWR���mgǶmWl�vŶ��m���Gݧ{����}O\�s�������J�ƶ�1['zf��D¶����; 9�������F�� �H `L$0"ba!b���!��sw075s"�RQT�����/�?"D������t47�!��&gt;��l�6N��cE%��� @dbn ��א�'��U!� ��� �̍��͍6�j"[�o�?"#[c�Bsd�vBБȀ��`d��p3��â#�8X�;:~����L l��s�dKdncd�l���t���}��9�~KX���m���휈��ʋ����NfN��v4�fٚ|K�9���o,�`��N�6�DN�o�-�!�����������7������pv4�1�/���VG�o�o���_q������Y��K��_R�郹�#�ʄ���ۦ�ӷmSs�D��Ė�������v��s8�+AT�� ��ƶ6V�D�FY[��Q�Ϫ�@��V�������������k�_#K�9�����C�9[Y�X7��/���������������"������#H:|w�����`b�n����Q��

Does anyone know how to make this HTML/PDF combination readable?

Answer (score 0):

Put 'Content-Type: application/pdf' in html header (before sending any data).
No HTML tags at all.

Comment: This is how server (source of pdf) should send if to http client.

Client can save the data stream to file - valid to be open with any pdf reader.
Please add your code to make clear what you are doing.

Comment: I added the code, can you see if you can make anything of it?

Comment: Then I see you are writing client side. The out you show '%PDF...' is a pdf stream which definitely is not a text file to be displayed directly.
You need to use some pdf rendering library (like iText or similar).
See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983730/java-pdf-renderer)
or
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082327/java-library-for-pdf-rendering) or [uncle google](https://www.google.pl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java%20rendering%20pdf)

Comment: I tried quite a few of those and I can't seem to make it work. I just need to make those question marks convert into text (like in a pdf file) and save it as a pdf. Any thoughts?

Comment: When I save the text to my desktop as a .pdf file, it displays a message saying that the file is damaged and could not be repaired.

Comment: Displaying pdf char by char in TextArea (or similar) is not possible without some pdf library (pdfreader). There are some simple pdfreader which fetch only text as java String and that you should be able to display.
Other thing is to make sure the sorce pdf is not corrupted. I understand from your comment that it is corrupted.